# Why does Group By not work as expected in my query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I m doing a query in Postgres Database where i want to fetch Sum of total amount following group by months. It is not working as expected. I really need help. Here is my query,

```
SELECT SUM(pi.total_amount) AS total_amount,
       status,
       accounts_approval_date,
       Cast(substring(accounts_approval_date, 4, 2) AS INTEGER) AS months
FROM proforma_invoice AS pi
WHERE pi.status = 'Accounts Approved'
  AND pi.created_by = 18
  AND substring(accounts_approval_date, 7, 4) = '2019'
GROUP BY months,
         pi.status,
         pi.proforma_invoice_id
ORDER BY pi.proforma_invoice_id DESC
```

Here is my output according to this query

[image]

Comment: you can try after removing accounts_approval_date, from selection as it is not part of GROUP BY clause

Comment: do you need to group by `pi.proforma_invoice_id`, and what happens if you also group by `accounts_approval_date`?

Comment: thanks @mkRabbani .. somehow it helped me.. but in case of group by we need to maintain the sequence

Comment: 1. remove the `invoice_id` from the group clause. 2. You can use `date_part('month', approval_date)` to get the month instead of your substring. 3. What do you mean with "maintain the sequence" can you add an example and the expected output?

Comment: You have shown us what you are getting, but not what you want to get instead.  The fact that you group by proforma_invoice_id but do not display that value certainly does not help clarify things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want one row per month, then remove `proforma_invoice_id` from the `group by` and `accounts_approval_date` from the `select`:

```
SELECT SUM(pi.total_amount) AS total_amount,
       status,
       Cast(substring(accounts_approval_date, 4, 2) AS INTEGER) AS months
FROM proforma_invoice AS pi
WHERE pi.status = 'Accounts Approved' AND
      pi.created_by = 18 AND
      substring(accounts_approval_date, 7, 4) = '2019'
GROUP BY months, pi.status
ORDER BY months;
```

If you want the invoice ids in the result set, you can use `ARRAY_AGG()` to bring in a *list*.